# Select Default Option if Blank HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, php-7

I would like a default selected value only if there is no data shown from the echo syntax. Can I get some assistance ? I've tried adding the "Selected" option but that just overrides the current data if any exist. Here is snippet of code is currently looking.

```
<td><div align="right"><strong>OUTPUT&nbsp;</strong></div></td>
<td><div align="left"><select name="OUTPUT" id="OUTPUT">

                                                            <option value="<? echo $output_id; ?> "><?php echo $output_status; ?></option>
                                                            <option value="1">Not Required</option>
                                                            <option value="2">Not Applicable</option>
                                                            <option value="3">Unknown</option>
                                                    </select></div></td>
```

Comment: put `value="your default option value"` on `select` element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your first option to the following will do the trick:

```
<option <?php echo (empty($output_id) ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?> value="<?php echo $output_id; ?> "><?php echo $output_status; ?></option>
```

If the value of `$output_id` is empty the option will be set to selected.

Comment: *"Try"* doesn't sound concrete. Your answer should read as: *"Use a ternary operator, such as the following:"*, IMHO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner True. I've updated the answer.